# Ubuntu freezes few minutes after login on SSD when any application is used

Tags: boot, ssd, freeze, crash

I had been using ubuntu on my Thinkpad e470, for almost 3 months.
Then I bought an SSD(870 EVO) and installed ubuntu 22.04 on it.

After the first restart everything worked fine but next day just minutes after login it froze. Every time there is somewhat even like very light use (like opening firefox or files) the system freezes.

I have read almost all previous SSD related freezing posts on various forums but none worked for me.
I tried with other distros (mint,kubuntu,lubuntu,popos,even manjaro and fedora) but all had the same problem.

This laptop used to have Windows and I never ever had any performance issues with it. So I installed windows 10 back and had no such freezing problems. I don't think its an SSD problem since all tests results are good, besides its working well with windows.
For now I have a dual boot config with ubuntu and windows 10 but can't use ubuntu due to freezing.

Here are some details about the freeze:

1. keyword/mouse not responding, keyword leds (caps lock, num lock)     frozen too. Can't open a console with Ctrl+Alt+F3 either.
2. No error led on the motherboard, no error sound either.
3. Screens are frozen too of course.

Only  solution: hard shutdown

Is anybody familiar with a method of fixing this or know whether if this is a bug?

Comment: If more then Ubuntu has an issue you have a hardware problem. Check and see if the SSD has a firmware upgrade.

Comment: Is it the model with Nvidia graphics? Did you install Nvidia drivers and disabled Secure Boot in UEFI? If not, there's your problem right there.

Comment: @David yes I have the latest firmware and no it has intel integrated graphics not a separate graphics card and I have secure boot disabled

Comment: new update!
One day I just booted into the ubuntu partition and it didn't freeze even after hours of use and just to be sure I kept using it for a week as my daily driver
then I replaced ubuntu with mint just to be sure if it was solved permanently and it also ran fine(this was not the case earlier ;all distros freezed) 
I seriously don't understand how but the problem is solved now.